# JDBC try block does not execute

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, prepared-statement

so the problem is that Try block code does not execute, what i can i do ? and where is the problem ?

```
public class verif {
    public static String checki(String pseudo, String mdp) {
        boolean check = false;
        String psDB = "", passDB = "";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet res;
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel", "naila", "pass");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select pseudo,mdp from recp");
            res = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (res.next()) {
                psDB = res.getString("pseudo");
                passDB = res.getString("mdp");
            }

            boolean us = psDB.equals(pseudo);
            boolean ps = passDB.equals(mdp);
            if (us && ps)
                check = true;
            else
                check = false;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        }
        return psDB;
    }
}
```

and this is the servlet :

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException { String pseudo=request.getParameter("username");
    String mdp = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();
    p.print("pseudo est "+verif.checki(pseudo, mdp));
  }
```

Comment: Two `Connection` objects in your code (`co` and `con`), and you use the one that is `null` ...

Comment: you are not moving the cursor you have to call `res.next()` try to use `if(res.next()){psDB=res.getString(1).toString();
  passDB=res.getString(2).toString();}`

Comment: where are they ?

Comment: same thing when i add if(res.next())

Comment: beside what does `recp.hotel` mean `schema.tablename`? or what exactly?

Comment: @RobinTopper i changed it but still have the same problem

Comment: @YCF_L it was a mistake i just remove it to only put recp and it's my tablename

Comment: Sounds like you should go through the code yourself and fix all obvious issues, and then come back with a clear problem/question.

Comment: @RobinTopper i just fix all obvious issues but still the same problem

Comment: @RobinTopper  i just edit my problem can you check it please

Comment: @YCF_L i just edit my problem can you check it please

Comment: ok can you please try to use `e.printStackTrace();` in the catch block maybe you have an error

Comment: beside your code will get correct result only and only the last row equal to your pseudo and mdp! instead your query should look like this `stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from recp pseudo = ? AND  mdp  = ?");` pass the inputs to your query and then check if you have results or not, you can just use `check = rs.next();`

Comment: I think your code should look like this https://ideone.com/

Comment: @YCF_L thank you the problem was with the mysql connector !

Answer (score 1):

```
Connection con = null;
Connection co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel" ,"naila","pass");
```

You have this 2 connections declared but in your prepared statement you use:

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("select pseudo,mdp from recp.hotel");
```

Just remove the **con** and use **co** and that should do the trick

Also, when you execute the prepared statement you get a cursor. and that cursor needs to be moved to the next position.
For example, if you think that multiple records will be returned the do:

```
while(rs.next()){  
  psDB=res.getString("pseudo");
  passDB=res.getString("mdp");
}
```

Comment: i changed it but still have the same problem

Comment: is pseudo and mdp represent my column ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the column names

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to call `next()` on the `ResultSet res` to point the cursor of `ResultSet` to the first record (if exists any). If you are not calling `next` method then that cursor will point just before the first result record and then the `res.getString(#)` will not return anything.

Just do this:

```
.
.
.
res = stmt.executeQuery();
while(res.next()){
    psDB = res.getString(1).toString();
    passDB = res.getString(2).toString();
}
.
.
.
```

Another hint is calling `res.getString(#)` will return values of type `String` and no need to call `.toString()` on them again. So it's better to change it like this:

```
.
.
.
res = stmt.executeQuery();
while(res.next()){
    psDB = res.getString(1);
    passDB = res.getString(2);
}
.
.
.
```

And it's a good practice to make the result of your sql as narrow as possible to only one record in this case (checking username and password for login purpose etc.). This means only select the password for the username which is passed to your `checki` method:

```
.
.
.
stmt = con.prepareStatement("select pseudo, mdp from recp where pseudo = ? ");
stmt.setString(1, pseudo);
res = stmt.executeQuery();
while(res.next()){
    psDB = res.getString(1);
    passDB = res.getString(2);
}
.
.
.
```

If you have any other errors after this, you may check that how many records do you have in your table and check to see if the record you are selecting in your code is there or not.

After that it may be because of some exception in your code which is caught by the `catch` clause but can not make any signal to inform you since you do nothing in the `catch` clause. Change your catch clause like this to see if any exception occurs or not:

```
}catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: i just try it and i still have the same problem

Comment: How many records do you have in your `recp` table? and are you sure that the `pseudo` and `mdp` columns are not null for all the records? since you are selecting all the records of `recp` table.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Check your `recp` table and find that record with a certain `pseudo` manually using some tools like MySQL query browser or something else you got. If you got sure that you have that record you are seeking, then check for any exception which may occur.

Comment: thank you the problem was with the mysql connector !

Comment: Glad that helped. Typically when an answer solves the problem or helps you find it you may want to mark it as the answer to your question. This also helps others to find solutions for their similar situations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be look like this.

```
public class verif {
    public static boolean checki(String pseudo, String mdp) {
        boolean check = false;
        String psDB = "", passDB = "";
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt;
        ResultSet res;
        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel", "naila", "pass");
            stmt = con.prepareStatement("select pseudo,mdp from recp where pseudo=? AND mdp=?");
            stmt.setString(pseudo);
            stmt.setString(mdp);

            res = stmt.executeQuery();
           /* Not  Needed
         while (res.next()) {
                psDB = res.getString("pseudo");
                passDB = res.getString("mdp");
            }

            boolean us = psDB.equals(pseudo);
            boolean ps = passDB.equals(mdp);*/
            if (res.next())
                check = true;
            else
                check = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return check;
    }
}
```

And Servlet Side code should be like this.

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{   
    String pseudo=request.getParameter("username");
    String mdp = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();
    if(verif.checki(pseudo, mdp)){
        // Put your Business Logic (Create session and redirect to Main Page)
        p.print("Successfully Logged in");
    }
    else{
        // Redirect to LogIn page
        p.print("Invalid Credential ");
    }

}
```